# Script to append multiple text files into single file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to Unix , I need to write a script. Can someone help me with a requirement where I have list of files in a directory, I want to Merge the files if a pattern of string matches in filenames?

```
AAAL_555A_ORANGE1_F190404_D190408.TXT.freshfruits_20190422-115617       
AAAL_555A_ORANGE2_F190404_D190408.TXT.freshfruits_20190422-115617       
AAAL_555A_ORANGE3_F190404_D190408.TXT.freshfruits_20190422-115617       
AAAL_555A_ORANGE4_F190404_D190408.TXT.freshfruits_20190422-115617     
AAAL_555B_ORANGE5_F190404_D190408.TXT.freshfruits_20190422-115617       
AAAL_555B_Orange6_F190404_D190408.TXT.freshfruits_20180422-115617
```

If second part of filename='555A' and third part consists of ORANGE then all Oranges/555A content files will merger into one file with filename as AAL_555a_Orange_date +"%Y%m%d".txt.

If second part of filename='555B' and third part consists of ORANGE/555B then all Oranges content files will merger into one file with filename as AAL_555b_Orange_date +"%Y%m%d".txt.

If second part of filename='555A' and third part consists of MANGO then all Mango content files will merger into one file with filename as AAL_555a_Mango_date +"%Y%m%d".txt.

Kindly help ..!

I know the below command to appended multiple files into one . But here i want to do based on patterns present in filename.

```
cat File1 file2 file3 >> final.txt
```

Something like this

```
for i in *.TXT; do    
   while field separator='_' read -r str1 num str2 ; do    
     if [ "$str1" = "RTG" ]; then    

     fi         
   done     
done
```

Comment: Your descriptions of which files should go together into which other file seem to contradict each other or contain typos, please revise them ("MANGO [...] all *Oranges* content files and similar). Can you describe the pattern to follow instead of giving three examples and have readers deduce the pattern?

Comment: Its an typo mistake now i have modified it . Kindly help @BenjaminW.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bash variable substitutions](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Script loops all the `AAAL`  starting files, stores their names to variable, `$in` and uses variable substitutions to process the names until there are only the second and third parts left (for example `AAAL_555A_ORANGE1_F190404.TXT` -> `555A_ORANGE`).

See the comments in the script for a step-by-step example and linked documentation for substitution explanation:

```
$ for in in AAAL*
  do                              # for example       AAAL_555A_ORANGE1_F190404.TXT
      out=${in#*_}                # remove AAAL_        -> 555A_ORANGE1_F190404.TXT
      out=${out%_*}               # remove _F190404.TXT -> 555A_ORANGE1
      out=${out%[0-9]}            # remove 1            -> 555A_ORANGE
      cat $in >> AAAI_$out.txt
  done
$ ls -1 AAAI*
AAAI_555A_MANGO.txt
AAAI_555A_ORANGE.txt
AAAI_555B_APPLE.txt
AAAI_555B_Orange.txt
AAAI_555B_ORANGE.txt
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail @James Brown

Comment: its not working if have we two digits after Orange like  ORANGE12
 AAAL_555A_ORANGE12_F190404_D190408.TXT.freshfruits_20190422-115617 @James Brown

Comment: Yeah, I noticed you changed the filenames but what's the expected output? Question is not very easily understood. Also, clean up all the mango references as the files don't have that word in them anymore.