# Filename manipulation

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Kindly help me with a unix script to modify the filename in required format as shown below:

```
AN_555a_orange_20190513.txt    
AN_555b_apple_20190513.txt
```

Required format: Fruits names first character should be in Caps and also its position should be is changed to second:

```
AN_Orange_555a_20190513.txt     
AN_Apple_555a_20190513.txt
```

And it should apply for all files present in directory,
below is the command i'm trying which is not working

```
for in in aaal*
  do
      out=${in#*_}
      out=${out%_*_*_*}
      out=${out%[0-9]}
      out1=${out#*_}
      out2=${out%_*}
      AAAI_$out1$out2.txt
  done
```

Comment: You could probably use this answer with slight modifications: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56062830/4162356

Comment: @JamesBrown, Yeah i have seen this and tried as well. But i could able to figure out the answer .Since am new to Unix shell Scripting. Kindly help me with that ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is simple, but worked with your sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in AN*; do
  NAME=$(echo $i | awk -F_ '{printf "%s_%s%s_%s_%s", $1,toupper( substr( $3,1,1)),(substr($3,2,100)),$2,$4,$5}')
  echo "--> $NAME"
done
```

Comment: you could omit the `100` to get the rest of the string with something like `awk -F_ '{printf "%s_%s%s_%s_%s\n", $1,toupper(substr($3,1,1)), substr($3,2),$2,$4}' `

Comment: Bingo..! That's worked as expected. Thanks a lot , But file names are not getting renamed .I guess mv step is missing . Could you please help me with that @nbari

Answer (score 0):

An interesting solution for this case is to use `sed`, just like this:

```sh
$ ls -1 | sed 's/\(AN_\)\([^_]*_\)\([a-z]*_\)\([0-9]*.txt\)/mv "&" "\1\u\3\2\4"/e'
```

Note the final `e` at the end of the sed command. It tells `sed` to execute the result of the substitution as a bash command.

So if you remove the `e` (which you could do at first, to check the substitution works as expected), you would get in the console:

```sh
$ ls -1 | sed 's/\(AN_\)\([^_]*_\)\([a-z]*_\)\([0-9]*.txt\)/mv "&" "\1\u\3\2\4"/'
mv "AN_555a_orange_20190513.txt" "AN_Orange_555a_20190513.txt"
mv "AN_555b_apple_20190513.txt" "AN_Apple_555b_20190513.txt"
```

(The `sed` substitution matches the several groups of characters, reorders them and creates the `mv ... ...` line. Note that `&` in the replacement pattern denotes the whole pattern matched, and `\u` tells `sed` to put the next character as upper case.)

Then add back that final `e`, and instead of printing these lines `sed` will *execute* them, effectively renaming the files.

Answer (score 0):

This onliner could give you more idas:

```
awk -F_ '{printf "mv %s %s_%s%s_%s_%s\n", $0, $1,toupper(substr($3,1,1)), substr($3, 2),$2,$4}' <(ls *.txt)
```

This will print something like:

```
mv AN_555a_orange_20190513.txt AN_Orange_555a_20190513.txt
mv AN_555b_apple_20190513.txt AN_Apple_555b_20190513.txt
```

Then if are happy with the results, pipe it to `sh` for example:

```
awk -F_ '{printf "mv %s %s_%s%s_%s_%s\n", $0, $1,toupper(substr($3,1,1)), substr($3, 2),$2,$4}' <(ls *.txt)  | sh
```

Comment: This is worked like a champ ..! i have one more query :  if i am having all lower case letters in filename like an_555a_orange_20190513.txt  then where to modify the above command to format it as AN_Orange_555a_20190513.txt @nbari

Comment: Give a try using only `toupper`, experiment until you get the desired results